# TypeError: Cannot serialize object Ellipsis of type <class 'ellipsis'>

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I am learning Tensorflow / Keras with the book "Deep Learning with Python". In chapter 8 it explains how to use a pretrained model. However, the provided code doesn't run and I get an error message when executing `model.fit`:

```
TypeError: Cannot serialize object Ellipsis of type <class 'ellipsis'>. 
To be serializable, a class must implement the 'get_config()' method.
```

I am using Tensorflow version 2.15.0

The program uses the dogs-vs-cats dataset from kaggle. It creates a smaller subset and creates a training, validation and test dataset. This all works as it is used for some other examples in the book. It then uses the pretrained VGG16 model and trains a dense layer connected to it

Here is my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

#upload kaggle.json file with the kaggle API Token 
from google.colab import files
files.upload()

!mkdir ~/.kaggle
!cp kaggle.json ~/.kaggle
!chmod 600 ~/.kaggle/kaggle.json

!unzip -qq dogs-vs-cats.zip
!unzip -qq train.zip

import os, shutil, pathlib
original_dir = pathlib.Path("train")
new_base_dir = pathlib.Path("dogs-vs-cats_small")

def make_subset(subset_name, start_index, end_index):
    for category in ("cat", "dog"):
        dir = new_base_dir / subset_name / category
        os.makedirs(dir)
        fnames = [f"{category}.{i}.jpg" for i in range(start_index, end_index)]
        for fname in fnames:
            shutil.copyfile(src=original_dir / fname, dst=dir / fname)

make_subset("train", start_index=0, end_index=1000)
make_subset("validation", start_index=1000, end_index=1500)
make_subset("test", start_index=1500, end_index=2500)

import pathlib

base_dir = pathlib.Path("dogs-vs-cats_small")

train_dataset = keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
    base_dir / "train",
    image_size=(180, 180),
    batch_size=32
)

validation_dataset = keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
    base_dir / "validation",
    image_size=(180, 180),
    batch_size=32
)

test_dataset = keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
    base_dir / "test",
    image_size=(180, 180),
    batch_size=32
)

#create neural network
conv_base = keras.applications.vgg16.VGG16(
  weights="imagenet",
  include_top=False
)
conv_base.trainable = False

data_augmentation = keras.Sequential(
    [
      keras.layers.RandomFlip("horizontal"),
      keras.layers.RandomRotation(0.1),
      keras.layers.RandomZoom(0.2)
    ]
)

inputs = keras.Input(shape=(180, 180, 3))
x = data_augmentation(inputs)
x = keras.applications.vgg16.preprocess_input(x)
x = conv_base(x)
x = keras.layers.Flatten()(x)
x = keras.layers.Dense(256)(x)
x = keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)(x)
outputs = keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")(x)

model = keras.Model(inputs, outputs)

model.compile(
    loss="binary_crossentropy",
    optimizer="rmsprop",
    metrics=["accuracy"]
)

callbacks = [
    keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
        filepath="features_extraction_with_data_augmentation.keras",
        save_best_only=True,
        monitor="val_loss"
    )
]

history = model.fit(  # error thrown here
    train_dataset,
    epochs=50,
    validation_data=validation_dataset,
    callbacks=callbacks
)
```

Comment: Always include the full traceback in the question itself.

Comment: The error seems to be that you put literally 3 dots, instead of example data. Does the "train_dataset" has the correct type and implement the `get_config` method?

Answer (score 3):

You can simply wrap the function `keras.applications.vgg16.preprocess_input` in `keras.layers.Lambda` as follows:

```py
...
x = data_augmentation(inputs)
x = keras.layers.Lambda(
     lambda x: keras.applications.vgg16.preprocess_input(x))(x)
x = conv_base(x)
...
```

`ModelCheckPoint` then should be able to save the model.
You would need to set `safe_mode=False` when you load the model with Lambda layer.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I am currently reading this book and running the provided code. I got the same  error and what works for is to save the model using the legacy *.h5* extension instead of *.keras*

```
callbacks = [
keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
    filepath="features_extraction_with_data_augmentation.h5",
    save_best_only=True,
    monitor="val_loss"
)]
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe functional model (unlike sequential) fails to save `keras.applications.vgg16.preprocess_input` part of the model (looks like a bug to me). The save attempts happens in the `ModelCheckpoint` callback.

For me (Apple Silicon, MacOS Sonoma 14.2.1, TF 2.15 with tensorflow-metal 1.1.0) using custom implementation for VGG16 preprocessing step works:

```
def preprocess_input(imgs):
    return tf.reverse(imgs, axis=[-1]) - tf.constant([103.939, 116.779, 123.68], dtype=tf.float32)
```

This can be used instead of `keras.applications.vgg16.preprocess_input`, it does the same transform but can be serialized successfully.